Mapping without collisions
This is abstracting the actual problem so it makes easier to understand (hopefully).
I have 1000 cards.  Each card has between 1 and 6 pictures of fruit.  There are 20 possible fruits.  Examples: one card could have a pineapple and a strawberry, another card could have a pineapple, pear, and raspberry, etc.
Now I need to change the fruit pictures to shapes like circles, triangles, squares, etc.  Easy-peasy: translate each fruit into a shape.  The challenge: I can only have 10 total shapes.  This means there will multiple fruits mapped to a single shape.  Example: oranges and grapefruit could be mapped to circles, pear and apples could be mapped to ovals, etc.
I need to avoid collisions when translating the cards: I cannot have more than one fruit translated into a single shape within a single card.  Grapefruit and oranges can be on different cards and this will be fine.  If grapefruit and oranges are on the SAME card, they would both be translated into the same shape (circle) and this would be bad.
The actual problem: there are multiple templates where certain fields are mapped to columns on a table, but some the datatypes do not match.  The vendor has added 10 more columns to the table with the correct data type!  I cannot change the data type of the existing columns.  I cannot add more columns.  I need to adjust the mapping to the new columns in cases where there is a datatype issue.  I need to avoid the described collisions.
If there were only a few cards, this could be done manually.  But given the large number of cards, a programic solution is required.

Your problem can be better understood under a mathematical lens, you are trying to build a bijection (one to one mapping) between a big set (set of fruits) and a smaller set (set of shapes).
Under the following conditions, that is impossible. Mainly because the sets are finite, discrete and are of different magnitudes.
If you allow the set of shapes to include more artificial elements, such as a subset of a powerset, that will solve your problem. In other words, you could add random pairs of pre-existing shapes as new elements in your set of shapes, until the set has enough elements for a bijection.

Yes, I was thought this would need a non-sql viewpoint. I didn't describe a one-to-one mapping ("The challenge: I can only have 10 total shapes").  Being the first to offer a solution (<60 min) that does not address the problem wouldn't be of goal of mine. I was hoping for a more programic solution, if one exists.
